# Is it possible to add another sync account to an existing contact in android?

Tags: android, contactscontract, android-syncadapter

What I want to do is creating a sync app and I'm doing it based on sync framework guideline now I am in a point that I don't want to do all the tedious job hence looking for a shortcut.

I want to add my sync account to existing contacts rather than mirroring contacts and aggregating them with the existing one. I just wanted to know is it possible to do such with the help of ContentProviderOperation?

if so is there any example of doing such? contacts in android is confusing too.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Android's contacts database doesn't provide enough meta data fields to do that. In particular the [ACCOUNT_NAME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#ACCOUNT_NAME) and [ACCOUNT_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#ACCOUNT_TYPE) columns exist only once for each contact. Also you wouldn't be able to use the mechanisms for efficient synchronization (DIRTY, DELETED, SOURCE_ID, SYNC1, ...) because those fields are used be the original sync adapter of the account and you would break it if you would modify any of these.